# Machine Learning: Creating Class Activation Map

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I recently followed this tutorial to train my own image classifier

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/?utm_campaign=chrome_series_machinelearning_063016&utm_source=gdev&utm_medium=yt-desc#0

for those who don't know it allows the retraining of a MobileNet network own your own custom images/categories. I have had sucess training networks on my own images using tensorflow but would like to go further now.

I now would like to generate a class activation map (CAM) for images inputted into the model. I have read you need your convolution neural network to have a Global Average Pooling layer for CAM's to work and am thinking the MoblieNet network does not have that. **Is it possible to generate CAM's from the network I have already trained or will I need to retrain using a different network like VGG16??**

**If it is possible could someone point me in the right direction on how to generate CAM's? If not could someone point me in the right direction on how to retrain a different network with my own images that will allow for CAM's and how to creat CAM's on these networks??**

Sorry for the vague nature of the question. I am by no means that familiar and/or trained regarding computer science but am interested to learn more. Your help would be greatly appreciate. Please contact me with further inquires about my question if needed. Hope to hear from you soon.

Thanks!